# Visual Studio, c++: run main() in dll?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm building a .dll application in Visual Studio with C++. I'd like to be able to run some test code (using `main()` and `std::cout`) to the console as I write to ensure that the code actually does what it's supposed to do.

But apparently, you can only build a .dll application and not run it.

Surely there's gotta be a way around this?

Comment: What is a _.dll application_? Doesn't DLL mean a Dynamic-Link Library? Which is used by applications (i.e., programs having `main` funcitons) to link functions from within at runtime?

Comment: If this is the Excel plugin from last week you can debug it in Visual Studio by changing the setting of the Debugging command in the property page for your target from `$(TargetPath)` to Excel (just browse for the executable). Then get Excel to load your plugin. And set breakpoints into your code.

Answer (score 2):

Write a test driver, a real application (a dll is not an application, it's a library), that will link against your dll and that will execute your tests.

That's the usual pattern as well for Boost.test, GoogleTest and many others unit test frameworks.

(that's a big hint to use a unit test framework for what you are doing)